# What do native speakers mean when they say "He could have stolen the ball"?

Tags: meaning, irrealis-mood

What do native speakers mean when they say "He could have stolen the ball"?

To them, does it mean that they suspect the subject to have stolen the ball or that the subject had the opportunity to steal the ball, but he didn't do so.

Someone told me it interpretes as the first of these two options. If so, how then does one express the other option?

Comment: Could mean either, depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

In general speech, 'he could have stolen the ball' means exactly what it appears to mean: He had the opportunity to steal the ball (and, depending on context, there may be a strong implication that the speakers suspects that he has done just that).

However, this **might** be an unfortunate example, because in some games and sports, 'stole the ball' is more likely to mean that a player obtained the ball through unusual skill, or through some unexpected circumstance.

e.g. "After Smith tripped, he fumbled and Jones could have stolen the ball had he moved a fraction faster."

Answer (score 1):

"Stolen" in the idiom is a sports reference (think football or basketball), not an actual theft of something.

"He had the opportunity to steal the ball, but he didn't do so" would be interpreted as the individual made a positive ethical/moral decision in the sense that he declined an opportunity to turn something to his own advantage.

Comment: If the goal is to gain possession of the ball, wouldn't it be a bad thing that the individual didn't do so?